# MySQL find count query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have table called `stats`. In am inserting `yes` or `no` in the table, and I want to show the number of yes count and the number of no count.

Can somebody please help me with the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN recommend = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) YesCount,
        SUM(CASE WHEN recommend = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) NoCount,
        COUNT(*) TotalCount
FROM    Stats
```

Comment: This what i asked..problem fixed

Comment: Bharanikumar: Please mark his response as the correct one... it's the empty thingy below the the point counter.

Answer (score 2):

```
select yn, count(*)
from stats
group by yn;
```

Comment: i dont have the yn field, i have only one field name is recommend tbl name is stats...

Comment: i tried somthing like this  "SELECT count(recommend)  FROM ".TBLRESULT." group by recommend  ";

Comment: As you didn't bother to tell us what columns were in your table, I made up a column name.

Comment: @Bharanikumar I'm downvoting your question as you failed to give the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the GROUP BY clause and aggregate functions are for in SQL.  The following should be what you need and more efficient then a CASE statement.  It returns a table with two columns: recommend and no (which is the count of identical values in the recommend column.  If what you said above is true, then this should return at most two rows.

```
SELECT recommend, count(*) AS no FROM stats GROUP BY recommend
```